# Рисовать линию между двумя объектами которые движутся snap svg

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, svg, snapsvg

Есть 2 круга. Они постоянно летают вверх и вниз. Через них должна проходить линия. Нужно чтобы линия постоянно перерисовывалась в зависимости от расстояние этих кругов. Т.е. при каждом движении.
С помощью snap svg*

```js
var paperHeader = Snap(".circle_anim");
var lineHeader = paperHeader.path("").attr({
  fill: "transparent",
  stroke: "#9b9b9c",
  strokeWidth: 2
});

function flyCircle(name_circle) {
  var element = Snap("#" + name_circle);
  var Bbox = element.getBBox();
  var coord_y = Bbox.cy;
  var states = [{
    cy: coord_y
  }, {
    cy: 500
  }, {
    cy: 320
  }];

  (function animateCircle(el, i) {
    el.animate(states[i], 2000, function() {
      animateCircle(el, ++i in states ? i : 0);
    });
  })(element, 0);
}

function drawLineHeader(circle) {
  var stringPath = lineHeader.attr("d");
  var element = Snap("#" + circle);
  var Bbox = element.getBBox();
  paperHeader.append(element);
  var coord_y = Bbox.cy;
  var coord_x = Bbox.cx;

  if (stringPath) lineHeader.attr({
    d: stringPath + "L " + coord_x + "," + coord_y
  });
  else lineHeader.attr({
    d: "M " + coord_x + "," + coord_y
  });
}

for (var count = 1; count < 8; count++) {
  var s_temp = "Hcircle" + count;
  drawLineHeader(s_temp);
  flyCircle(s_temp);
}
```

```css
.circle_anim {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="circle_anim">
  <circle id="Hcircle1" fill="#9B9B9C" cx="0" cy="60%" r="9" />
  <circle id="Hcircle2" fill="#9B9B9C" cx="6%" cy="99%" r="9" />
  <circle id="Hcircle3" fill="#9B9B9C" cx="23%" cy="78%" r="9" />
  <circle id="Hcircle4" fill="#9B9B9C" cx="40%" cy="82%" r="9" />
  <circle id="Hcircle5" fill="#9B9B9C" cx="65%" cy="91%" r="9" />
  <circle id="Hcircle6" fill="#9B9B9C" cx="80%" cy="99%" r="9" />
  <circle id="Hcircle7" fill="#9B9B9C" cx="100%" cy="55%" r="9" />
</svg>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.2.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gtrm1nu3/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Набросал пример в jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvkzcqq4/4/)

Суть данного решения сводится к тому, что необходимо распарсить атрибут d у линии `line.attr('d')` и установить для него новое значение.
За это отвечает функция `parseLineAttrs`

Так же сделал анимацию другим способом. Здесь заменил путь на линии и анимирую их, это позволило избавиться от парсера пути и производить анимацию более понятно `{x1, y1, x2, y2}`
[Способ с линиями](http://jsfiddle.net/uvkzcqq4/8/)

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам! Вы не представляете как нереально помогли!

Comment: А как сделать чтобы они хаотично летали? Я сделал 2 пути и раз через раз каждому кругу даю разный путь. Но я не понимаю какой путь нужно передать линии, чтобы она тоже следовала правильно - http://jsfiddle.net/uvkzcqq4/9/

Comment: Все очень просто. В данном случаи надо 2 стейта. Первая точка линии анимируется по 1му стейту, вторая точка по 2му. [http://jsfiddle.net/uvkzcqq4/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/uvkzcqq4/14/)

Comment: Как Вы это делаете? я 2 недели пытался это сделать. Всю документацию по snap перерыл. Офгиеть. Большое Вам, еще раз, спасибо!

Comment: @DanielMorozov snap тут не причем =) Достаточно просто представить что и как должно анимироваться на каждом из шагов. Уверен, что имея такую картинку перед собой - вы бы с легкостью решили эту задачу. [картинка](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image857673.jpg) . Т.е. мы видим, что каждая точка анимируется согласно своему states. Значит и линия (а это и есть 2 точки - 0 и 1, 1 и 2, 2 и 3, ...) должна анимироваться по этим правилам.